# Is someone vote-spamming me?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I just logged on after being away for about an hour, and was met with this:

[image]

I checked, and all of my questions and answers were upvoted.

Is this just a crazy coincidence, or am I being vote-spammed?

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: Happened to me too. Looks like someone *really* liked one of your answers, so he upvoted as much as he can.

Comment: Did it take your rep away? That's interesting. What if they actually liked all your questions and answers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like vote spam to me, but there's nothing to worry about. Stack Exchange has automated systems built in for detecting serial voting and will reverse the votes if it thinks anything suspicious is going on.

Comment: How many is "serial voting"?

Comment: @Alex We can't and we don't have to know that. There's a complex system behind, and it's kept secret to avoid people to profit with it.

Comment: I'm fairly certain they use a [random number generator](http://www.xkcd.com/221/) to determine the number of votes that are considered "serial". Yep, definitely.